# Google not indexing home page

Tags: seo, google, google-search

I have two sites that I'm trying to generate traffic with, and for whatever reason, Google does not seem to want to index the home pages.  Other pages on the site are indexing just fine.

I need to get these home pages indexed obviously, or perhaps reassess strategy if it's not going to happen.  Has anyone seen this before, or can see something wrong with my home pages from Google's perspective?

Comment: As I answered in https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content/108524#108524 it could easily be due to the presence of a robots.txt file telling Google not to index the site.  Simplest solution is to rename that file to robots.bak and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is weird. I've only seen things like this if a page is penalised or has been purposely excluded from the index for some reason. Google Webmaster Tools is your friend here and will tell you if there have been any errors with the page. Try fetching the page as Google-bot and see what comes back. Also, use tools like Open site explorer and have a look at your link profile...are there any links from bad places? If so get them removed and resubmit the page.

This is a [useful thread on Google Webmaster Forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking/_lkwnCxWW9U), Good luck and let us know what is happening!

Comment: The fetch as Googlebot solved it for me.  The previous developers had programmed in some ugly SQL queries that were failing due to a bot not being assigned an ID as a normal visitor would.  I saw the error when I fetched as Google bot, and fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the source code other than double forward slashes being generated in your script tags and links such as `http://www.dcedental.com//category/endodontics`

If you recently made changes you'll just need to wait for Google to re index and cache your home page. You can look in Webmaster Tools to see which of your pages have the most incoming links, and if your home page is linked to the most from other pages within your domain you should get it indexed and cached but when is up to Google.