# How long does Google Webmaster Tools take to index a website?

Tags: google-search-console, htaccess, search-engines, search-engine-indexing

How much time does Google Webmaster Tools take to index a page? Analytics took around 24 hours to get info from the site, but since this is indexing, I guess it might take a little bit more than that. I would like to know though, an estimate so that I can start working on redirecting traffic with search engines to my sites so that it gets indexed much better.

**EDIT**

I just tried indexing with bingbot and the following messaged appeared when I hit on fetch as bingbot:

> REDIRECTION LIMIT REACHED

What does that mean?

According to the code it brings back, only a a few parts of the site are returned, then it goes away to God knows where.

Inside my `.htaccess` file I wrote the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Could it be possible that something of my `.htaccess` file could be redirecting the bot or something like that?

Comment: If your website/content aren't indexed by search engine, check the answers of this question. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content

Comment: Regarding your htaccess update - it looks OK (although you have a few superfluous lines - no need to enable the RewriteEngine twice, or check for mod_rewrite, for instance). Only your first rule is a _redirect_ (that could possibly cause bingbot to complain). Providing you are linking to HTTPS (not HTTP) throughout your site and in your sitemap etc. then this should be OK.

Comment: Well @w3d is there a way to force https without redirecting the user, and any bots particularly?

Comment: The redirection is primarily there for when users accidentally navigate to the non-HTTPS version of your site. Ordinarily, users (and bots) won't see this redirection, so it shouldn't be an issue, providing you are already linking to the HTTPS version throughout. AFAIK there is no other way, other than not including the redirection and _not_ having your site accessible over HTTP at all (which is actually better from a security point of view, if that is a concern).

Comment: HTTPS is already being linked throughout the entire site, the only part of the website I want to force HTTPS on is on the main page, on the index, but if that's going to harm the site's ability to be indexed, then I rather not. Question is though, how does `facebook` and `google` force redirection to `https` and they don't get any harm towards their indexing?

Comment: Well, that's the thing... what you are doing (above) should not harm your site at all and it is a puzzle why the bingbot should report such a problem - there would seem to be something else going on here? Facebook and Google do exactly the same thing... they issue a 302 (301 in the case of Google) external redirect from HTTP to HTTPS (you can see this if you look at the network traffic in your browser). Does the bingbot give you an idea of what URLs are causing the problem? Check your own network traffic in the browser and access logs to see if a redirect loop is being triggered somehow.

Comment: I tried using the tool that bing webmaster tools has, which is `Fetch as Bingbot`curious thing is, if I put https://hsoto.me which is the domain, it gets to it just fine, but if I put http://hsoto.me it tells me `Redirection Limit Reached`. Google does fine, but Microsoft in the other hand can't do that apparently.

Comment: This question is continued here... http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56676/301-redirect-causing-bingbot-to-crash-redirection-limit-reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if your post is index and is added in SERP. If not try to do this:

If you go to **Crawl** then **Fetch as Google**, do **Fetch** the page then **Submit to Index**.

Check after a minute, then your page is index and included in SERP. Based from my own experience. I hope you too will have this experience.

Comment: I'm a new webmaster, and this is all new to me. I already verified if my site is indexed and it's not. entered this on google search bar: `site:http://hsoto.me` and it's not indexed. Where is crawl though? Help

Answer (score 1):

**There is no estimated time for Google Webmaster Tools to index a website.**

It mainly depends upon the following factors

1. Popularity of the site (Whether it has any
   links to it)
2. Whether the content is crawl-able (Server Responses and Content
   type)
3. Site structure (how pages interlinked)

If you submit a sitemap of the website in GWT, it would allow Google to easily index your website but there is no exact time period for indexing a website.