# How long before Google indexes a new (to me) domain that previously had spam and virus problems?

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, google-index, block

I registered a new ".com" domain, but when I added it to the Google Search Console I saw that there were problems with viruses and spam problems. I submitted a request for reconsideration. Google replied (about 2 days) that everything was cleaned and the domain was approved, but my site does not appear in Google's search.

How much time should I wait for the site to appear in search?

Update:

I do not know the history of the domain and the previous owner

1) I fix this problem: "Search Console" -> "Search Traffic" -> " Manual Actions" -> "Pure spam" (in all site) https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2604777?hl=en

2) I fix this problem: "Search Console" -> "Security Issues" -> "Viruses"

"Search Console" -> "Crawl Stats" -> "Crawl" Curve line goes

"Search Console" -> "Crawl Stats" -> "Sitemaps" Pending (3 days)

Also, there is a Adsense blockage, but I did not give the unblocking request to Adsense because in the first place I'm waiting for the domain to appear in the search. (In the Adsense I have no messages about this domain, but ads are not showing).

No backlinks

site:******.com Shows nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long does Google Webmaster Tools take to index a website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56638/how-long-does-google-webmaster-tools-take-to-index-a-website)

Comment: I don't think that is a  duplicate.  That other question is about a new site that didn't have virus or spam problems.

Comment: Google's Matt Cutts has a video on this subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oofc9owVowg

Answer (score 4):

This is the very interesting situation as you didn't know the history of the domain.

There are several things you may need to look.

1. Virus vs Spam: Check if it had infection issue or it was penalised by Google due to poor SEO practice.
2. If only virus issue then it's not that hard to fix, send the request and generally Google updates in about 24 hours if the website will be clean. Just check your site by typing site:yoursite.com and see if Google is indexing your page.

But if the website was penalised then it might be a bit hard get all cleared and my take longer. You may need to disavow poor links.

So, your priority should be to understand the domain history and communicate with Google to get this sorted.

Time: it may take few days to weeks depending on the issue domain may have.

Answer (score 4):

I was pretty much in the same boat, save for the fact that mine was not an issue with spam or viruses. Instead, I had loads of broken links from when the domain was owned by someone else.

**Patience**

My advise to you is to be patient. As you say, you have already notified Google about the problem and they have cleared and approved the domain.

Your site will appear in Google between 4 days and 4 weeks after launch, so you need to take a deep breath. There are many things that you can do meanwhile;

- Produce great content
- Use social Media to boost your visibility
- Carry out on and off page SEO

Again: Patience

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I registered a new domain to start everything from a blank sheet. But the answer to my question is 2-3 weeks.