# Putting a website in a directory above the public_html,Can search engines find it?,Is this website crawled by search engines?,What is the solution?

Tags: search-engines, googlebot

I have a Linux web host and I have added some other domains beside the main domains,as add-ons domains.

I have created a directory beyond the main public_html directory,
for each of them,and all of thier contents are in those directories,you can open the websites,by typing their URL in browser,but nearly more than two month after the creation of the websites;

after searching their URL in Google,nothing is showed up in the search results,for example if you search the "yahoo.com" phrase in google,the number one result would be the http://yahoo.com result,but I assume the search engines could not crawl a website in a directory beyond the public_html,is this true?

what is the solution?

Please note that I am not talking about Google specifically,I am asking about all of the Bots on the web.

and about the directory,I meant for example in the website1,website2,website3 directories.

```
   /website1
   /website2
   /website3
   /mail
   /logs
   /includes
   /public_html
       /images
       /admin
       /users
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search engines can crawl any documents found inside of the webroot (in your case public_html) and any directories with it. They cannot directly access documents below your webroot.

For example, assume the following directory structure:

```
/website1
/website2
/website3
/mail
/logs
/includes
/public_html
/images
   /admin
   /users
```

Unless specific measures are put in place to prevent this, for your main website, search engines can access all of the documents in `/public_html`. This includes documents in `/images`, `/admin` and `/users`. They cannot access documents in `/mail`, `/logs` and `/includes`. They can only access documents from those directories if the website creates a mechanism for serving those files. (This is typically done through a pass through script of some kind which is available inside of the webroot).

In the case of addon domains, whatever directory you specify as the webroot, even if it is below your main website's `/public_html` directory, is that website's webroot and all of the above applies for that website. So for website1, `/website1` is the webroot and search engines can access all of its content including the content in the subdirectories.

So to your real problem, if you cannot find your web pages when doing a search for your website name or domain, then you have some major SEO issues going on. There's no way for us to know but you can start to figure this out by reading [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: thanks for migrating and editing my question,actually I meant the directory above the public_html,not below.I will explain more.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks A Lot,But Actually I've understood that you mean the /websit e1 is accessible,and it's an SEO issue right?

Comment: Yes. Something is keeping the search engines from indexing your content.

Comment: thanks,but because,this is happens for more than 3 websites,I have suspected about the directories structure and server issue,is that possible to test a website to see if it's crawlable with Bots or not?

Comment: Google Webmaster Tools offers a tool for this. It will also report errors with your site.