# How do I troubleshoot users having issues paying on my site with Paypal

Tags: web-development, paypal, users

We are using Express Checkout for taking payments on a site.

It seems like the site was working fine in sandbox testing and in production for some time.

We have, however, received word that a user was unable to make a payment.

Details are sparse at the moment and the task of finding out what the hell is wrong has fallen to me.

The only problem, is that I can't seem to find a lot of troubleshooting documentation to help me determine where in the long line of actors the problem might lie.

**What questions should I be asking to help determine whether the fault of a payment issue resides with me, the customer, or Paypal?**

Comment: If it's one user then it's most likely user error. Unless you can reproduce it or get wide ranging reports of failure you can't go nuts over one user failing. You still try to figure it out but the burden lies on them to provide you with as much info as possible.

Comment: I can understand why you put the question on hold, but could this question not be made into a catch-all kind of question (similar to [this one](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)) for more general troubleshooting help with PayPal payments on a site?

Comment: It's really broad and not asked often. Neither make for a good catch-all question.

Comment: Sure, I understand, I'll ask another more specific question if I can get more details on the issue, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @RedRiderX Try and get details as to where the user got stuck and update the answer. It may be that it is a PayPal problem. I would be walking the user through the process as if they were doing it again and try and understand each step before they go to the next- that way they do not out-run you. John is right. It may be just a hiccup. If you can walk the user through the process and it works, problem solved! You are a genius!!