# Submitted site on bing webmaster still not being indexed

Tags: bing

I had submitted my website on Bing webmaster before three days but it is still not being crawled and indexed at bing.. is there any way that i can index my site on Bing?

Comment: There really aren't enough details here for users to be able to answer specifically, and we have many questions on [indexing and Bing](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=index+bing+is%3Aquestion) already. For general SEO questions like this, we usually refer to [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google) frequent question and:  [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content), which apply to Bing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines are notoriously slow. Bing can be especially. As well, Bing does not index all sites. It has criteria that it uses to include a site. Even then, Bing may not index all pages. It has criteria for that too.