# I have two websites , one has over 8000 pages indexed the other has less than hundred,why is this happening?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, search-engine-indexing

Both sites were created with the same platform and have similar layout , their age is only a few days apart but one site is having problem getting indexed above 120pages out of the 18000+. I have submitted a sitemap and all

Comment: There isn't enough details here to be able to answer this, and questions specific to individual website reviews for SEO purposes are off-topic here. See:  [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)