# Could my personal hosting package be blacklisted by Google? New sites created with it won't rank

Tags: google, google-search-console

I've had a website design site up for a while now, it's very localised (mentions target town heavily without stuffing) but doesn't appear until page 7 on a reasonably worded localised search (website design [town]) (there's stuff PAGES ahead of it that has nothing to do with the search).

It has had zero clicks for months (see below). I've almost given up wondering what on earth I've not done/done wrong. Strangely. whenever I build and launch a site for others they're on pages 1 or 2, but sites I build for my self can't get ranked above page 5.

Could it be that my personal hosting package is being targeted by some black hatters?

[image]

Comment: How many versions of your site have you added to search console?  With and without "www"?  Both HTTP and HTTPS?   Adding all four can help.   Google will usually only report data for the one to which it actually sends traffic.

Comment: One with, one without, with the 'with' being the preferred domain, both http, no https.

Comment: Does your site support HTTPS?   Google usually sends traffic to HTTPS is both are available.

Comment: I don't have a certificate for the site as it's only interactive through a contact page.

Comment: OK, then that doesn't sound like it is the problem.

Comment: I can pm you a link to the site if you like?

Comment: See: [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: I've edited your question to focus on the part of your question that isn't covered in [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content).   The rest of your question is duplicate of that.