# Google Search Console reports my URLs are indexed but they are not showing in search result even for a site: search

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-index

All my URLs has been indexed and is showing in Google search result except for `/product` directory. For example you can search in Google:

```
site:https://www.zanemroozi.com/product/
```

Google Search Console is showing the indexed directory but not showing in Google search result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a screenshot from Google Search Console that shows that the URLs are indexed?    It really sounds like a case of [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content) to me.

Comment: Sometimes people accidentally submit things for removal with the URL removal tool in Search Console -- you might want to double-check there. In cases like that, Google might have it indexed, but not shown in search (the URL removal tool removes/hides it in the  search results, it doesn't remove it from the index).

Comment: I see this search now returns results ("About 2,450 results") - did you have to do anything specific to fix this?

Comment: I think I have the same problem with my site https://site-de-streaming.com but never see any solution here !

Answer (score 2):

site:example.com is very useful, but it's not 100% accurate. Many pages may be indexed with Google that aren't shown with the site: search parameter. It's quite common for websites to have more pages indexed according to search console than displayed using site: and in fact, almost all of my sites have more pages indexed according to search console than when I use site:

It's said that search console is more accurate than using the site: search parameter. If Google says that those pages are indexed than they should be.

It's also possible that if those pages don't show up when using site: then there's a chance that they will rank less than your other pages and may not receive traffic. Google may display those pages with site: and send them more traffic at a later time.

Comment: "site:example.com is very useful, but it's not 100% accurate." - yes, but it is generally better than 0% accurate. If there are _some_ pages indexed, then you would expect a `site:` search to at least return _something_.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same challenge one time. For the sake of others that may have the the same challenge:

Remember to use your canonical URL when using `site:example.net`
`http://www.example.com` is different from `http://example.net`
In your Google Search Console, remember to add your both variants of your domain name and monitor their search status. 
However, your canonical URL is more important.

Wondering what your canonical is? 
It is the variant of your site that you choose to display in search results. 
It helps to prevent duplicate content in search results.
It is usually specified by the link tag in the head section of your page, as follows:

`<link rel="canonical" content="www.example.net"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) in Google Search Console in order to check if there is any problem accessing or indexing this section.

> The Fetch as Google tool enables you to test how Google crawls or renders a URL on your site. You can use Fetch as Google to see whether Googlebot can access a page on your site, how it renders the page, and whether any page resources (such as images or scripts) are blocked to Googlebot

Comment: As I said before, my URLs are indexed but do not show in google search result. I used Fetch as Google before :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try searching the subdomain in Google search? I mean like keying in:

```
domain.com/products
```

in the search box? What do you see? Or perhaps check it by keying in the search box:

```
"product name" site:domain.com/products
```

Check it if it's indexed, if you can see the URL in the results page, it's indexed. If you can't see it, can you please double check that the subdirectory is not blocked in `robots.txt`? There might be instances that it might be a bug in Google console.

Comment: "did you try searching the subdomain in Google search?" - (presumably you mean "subdirectory"?) but that's what the `site:` search example is doing in the question. (?)

Comment: don't use the "site" parameter. just do a simple search and enter the site url as the search phrase

Answer (score -2):

Give some Backlinks to your Webpage URLs and use Google Fetch Tool as said above.

But Prefer Backlinks Because it Helps you In All the Way...

Comment: Yes backlinks generally help get pages indexed, but you don't answer the question.   Why are the pages indexed according to Google Search Console but never showing up in search results?

Comment: the topic is clear from my above answer. Google Finds your Webpage but Cant Index that due to the non-deep crawling of the page. But when you give BLs Then It will Crawl more deeply and Easy for Google and You to index that page. I apologize if you cant understand my short Answer Completely.