# My URL can't be index in Google Search Result

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, search-results, noindex

I am not sure why my URL is not indexed on the Google SERP when I check it by `site:`. Here what I have done so far:

- Submit the URL via "Fetch as Google" on Google Search Console
- URL is on the Sitemap and Resubmitted on Google Search Console
- I submitted the URL via Crawl
  URL(https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url)

I also have this checklist:

- The web page doesn't have `noindex`
- the URL is not blocked by robots.txt
- Not part of 404 Error/Server Error or any Crawl Error listed on the
  Console

I do wonder it is not been crawled and indexed. It has been a week that I monitor it but nothing is happening. Do anyone have a clue what may be the reason for it?

Comment: It would be hard for us to definitively say, other than taking guesses... Have a look at this question to see if that provides some ideas:  [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: The site directive is not how you determine a page has been indexed. In fact, it is about as poor an indication there can be. Any search query will, regardless of the query, be processed by a long list of SERPs filters which will filter out pages and order pages. Just because you do not see it in the SERPs does not mean the page has not been indexed. Ask yourself this. Is there a reason why the page would not pass all of the filters? Also, have you allowed enough time for Google to do it's work? Cheers!!

Comment: More info needed: 1) Is it a brand new domain  and website? 2) If not then explain in detail about what is not getting indexed?

Comment: Also check it has not been removed by the GSC remove URL tool and it is not excluded via the URL parameter tool. You could make a sitemap with just that file to see if it has been indexed. And check the beta search console as that provides more details on crawling/indexing issues.