# Could using the Google URL removal tool for a specific page also have removed the home page?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, googlebot, search-results

I noticed today my Homepage URL is not on Google Search Result anymore. Firstly for specific keyword where i ranked #1 than for domain itself.  it is my brand keyword which I get most traffic from.

I checked pretty much everything, Google Search Console doesn't show any anomalies and penalties as well.

The only thing i am not sure about is that yesterday I removed a URL from Google Search Console: `https://www.example.com/page.html`.  Could removing this page also cause the home page to get removed?

I also noticed that I can find my homepage on Google but it is indexed as `https://www.example.com/index.html` even though I redirected index pages in .htaccess long ago.

Searching `site:example.com`, many of pages are still there, but most of them are in other language too (eg. `example.com/de`)

Comment: We can answer the question about whether or not the removal tool could have caused the home page removal, but for general "why aren't my pages indexed" problems please see [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: Thanks Stephen! i did not want to make a question that specific in order to get other/more information which could be relevant for URL removal tool. Somehow i get this issue a bit more broad since i couldnt find any information on this isue sepcifficaly.

Comment: "Could removing this page also cause the home page to get removed?" - in short, no. Presumably `/index.html` still 301 redirects to `/`? A `site:` search can still return the source of redirects. If you are seeing `/index.html` in the SERPs then it perhaps suggests that `/index.html` is still being linked to, either on your site or by 3rd parties.

Comment: Check your home page using the new search consoles URL inspector. It may give you more details on why it seems to be not indexed.

Comment: @Tony McCreath - oh great! didnt know for that feature