# My site is indexed. Why does Search Console not reflect that?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index, idn, punycode

[image]

There is only one page is indexed, and it is the homepage. **Yet, it seems that my site is indexed successfully, tested by searching for random excerpts.** There is `google / organic` entry in my Google Analytics. My property is verified with domain name. There is no robot.txt in my directory. My site map is OK. The search console property for my site is created for about a month ago. My domain has no www or https.

When inspecting a specific URL `http://example.com/articleA`, it says it's indexed, not submitted in sitemap. However, the sitemap does contain this URL.

One important thing: it is an [internationalized domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name). That is, it contains non-Latin characters, and needs to be encoded in [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)  (`quảcầu.cc`→`xn--qucu-hr5aza.cc`)

There seems to be nothing else to check, according to [About our stats and data - Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96568?hl=en) or [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/43351/52079). So do you know what happens?

Comment: Googles Search Console is notoriously slow. Some of this is for a reason. I find that it can be about a month or two behind. Cheers!!

Comment: Double check that you are looking at EXACTLY the same urls in these different spots. http is different to https. With www is different to without www. Case is important. Are they exactly the same for your Search Console account, in your sitemap, in the search results in the reports?

Comment: @TonyMcCreath My domain has no www or https, but it does contains non-ASCII characters, so it needs to be encoded with punycode. However it doesn't seem that Search Console has trouble to understand it

Comment: Try entering in one of your URLs into the URL Inspection tool. Maybe one you have seen in the search results. Double check how Google is dealing with the encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wait longer and it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Google is most likely indexing a variant of your site that doesn't match the variant that you added to Google Search Console.   It is very common not to see data in search console when it does not match.

Normally, I would suggest adding four URL prefix properties to Google Search Console with all variations of `www` / no-`www`, `http` / `https`.  With punycode thrown in there, I would add all eight variations:

- `http://quảcầu.cc/`
- `http://xn--qucu-hr5aza.cc/`
- `https://quảcầu.cc/`
- `https://xn--qucu-hr5aza.cc/`
- `http://www.quảcầu.cc/`
- `http://www.xn--qucu-hr5aza.cc/`
- `https://www.quảcầu.cc/`
- `https://www.xn--qucu-hr5aza.cc/`

Your search console data should be on one of those.

Alternately you could verify two "domain properties" for just:

- `quảcầu.cc`
- `xn--qucu-hr5aza.cc`

Comment: thank you for your input. I imagine ignore this question is much easier for you? So thank you