# Google Search Console reports my site is only appearing in the search results for 8 keywords

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, keywords, meta-keywords

Google Search Console is only showing 8 keywords in the search analytics report. It's been more than two months since last keyword appear there. I want to know the reason why that report isn't listing more.

I have verified Google Search Console for another site in the same niche, and it showed 47 keywords in search queries within two to three weeks.

What could be the possible reason? I just checked the difference between both sites and the website with fewer keywords has a plugin installed called Really Simple SSL to secure my website. I just deactivated now, could it have been the problem?

Now I am creating backlinks, but still it is not increasing keywords in search console.

Comment: You tagged this as [Tag:meta-keywords] but Google ignores meta keywords.  Do you use keywords in the visible text on the site?  If you only use them in your meta keywords, it won't help with Google.

Comment: You may also be interested to the answers to [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google) and [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! Please know that Google Search Console is notoriously slow... very very slow.

Comment: Okay do let me know that is it okay if I have used a plugin for ssl certificate "Really Simple SSL" plugin?