# I'v indexed my pages in search console, but Google didnt show them in search results

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

I have indexed all of my webpages into google search console tools.. but Google did not show the results in search results.

Can you help me please.. see the latests articles, they wont show in search results

Comment: you can't "index" your pages in Search Console.   At most you can submit them as part of a sitemap.   Google decides whether they are worth indexing and showing in search results separately.  You can't force Google to index any particular page.

Comment: thanx for the inswer.. can you please tell me why the latest articles are not shown in google please ?

Comment: Take a look at [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content) which should give you many ideas for making your pages attractive enough for Google to index.