# Google Search Console reports "Crawled - currently not indexed" for many pages

Tags: seo, google-search-console, wordpress

What are the possible reasons for this? What Can I do? How to Indexing the URL's. Almost All URL's are Not Indexing in SERP's.

[image]

Its About Manga/Comic Website. Almost 35 days Old Domain. There are a lot of exclude tab issues. But one of the major issue is "Crawled - currently not indexed". Anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: "Crawled - currently not indexed" - That's not necessarily an "issue". https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203?hl=en

Comment: I re-opened your question but then marked it as a duplicate.  You can find the answer to your question at [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the html tab in GSC of any of your unreachable pages to see if the "noindex" tag is in the html that GSC returns?  Have you modified your .htaccess file?

Something is obviously telling Google not to index these pages.

You might also try turning off all of your plugins, recrawl a test page via https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ to see if Google can crawl the page.  Then turn one plugin on at time to see if you have a plugin causing the problem.

Comment: Google is detecting a lot of duplicate pages. This is probably a signal to them that it is not worth crawling the rest. Hence a lot of discovered but not indexed (not crawled)

Comment: @TonyMcCreath, good point.  I only looked at the errors.