# GSC Error: "Page indexed without content"

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index

My client's GSC is saying the home page is "indexed without content". When I inspect the URL, it says it is not on Google. Clicking further into the issue seems to indicate that some sort of redirect is in place and that these referring URLs redirect to my client's website:

- https://www.cupcakecottage.digigrow.com/
- https://digigrow.com/

How in the world do I go about fixing this? Any help is appreciated!

[image: GSC]

[image: GSC]

Comment: Neither if those links work correctly due to SSL cert problems. Are you aware of that?

Comment: Looking past the SSL errors - what are you expecting to happen? Those urls do nothing but redirect to the actual website & they have no content so Google has ni content to index.

Comment: Yes, aware that they have the cert problem. I am not sure how this redirect was put into place. I am trying to figure out how to un-do this redirect in a sense so that we can index the actual website and eliminate the GSC error if that makes sense.

Comment: How is this in any way stopping you from indexing your actual website?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "cloaking."  Cloaking is usually defined as serving different content to Googlebot than to normal users.    I'm not sure how other domains that redirect to your site could possibly cause that.

Comment: Okay so this is definitely not my area of expertise - edited question to eliminate the cloaking aspect. When I try to index the actual website it tells me that the URL is not on Google. I request indexing, but get the pictured message of "URL will be indexed only if certain conditions are met. It takes me to this page for guidance: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289#live_indexable. From here I'm not sure what to do to resolve this?

Comment: Google doesn't index everything.  They choose what to index and what not to.   See [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how and why the https://www.cupcakecottage.digigrow.com/ and
https://digigrow.com/ are redirecting to my site, and how this could be potentially affecting my inability to request indexing for the actual URL.