# Has Google completely stopped indexing new pages in the last two weeks?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

On our website, new pages have not been indexed for more than two weeks. The content is unique. There are no errors or warnings at all in Google Search Console. The site scores 100/100 on Pagespeed Insights.

Is this something that is specific to our site or has Google stopped indexing all new pages for some reason?

Comment: Related: [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: Based on your [comments on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70114974/why-have-new-pages-stopped-being-indexed-via-the-search-console) I have taken a stab at re-phrasing the question in a way that is not just about your site.

Comment: There are some claims that Google has stopped indexing altogether but that is incorrect (see article). However there is significant discussion on social media backed with data to support that Googlebot indexing patterns have changed. https://www.searchenginejournal.com/googlebot-crawling-reduced-data/427238/. As of now, answers to this question can only be speculation.

Comment: I have just every page gives the title "Last-Modified, If-Modified-Since and 304 Not Modified".
And I don't have a cookie confirmation panel. I will experiment.

Comment: Thanks for the article!

Answer (score 1):

Google has not stopped indexing new pages and I can prove it.  This page with your question on it is now indexed.  I can search for the title of this page in quotes and bring it up:

[image: Google search result for this question]

There must be a reason specific to your site that Google isn't indexing your new pages.   There are several such possible reasons.  See [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content) In your case the content on your pages is not very unique.  Pretty much every phrase on the example page you had provided is also found on other pages.   Try searching Google for a each phrase from your site in quotes. I spot checked several  phrases and in each case found other pages that used that same phrase.

Comment: That's not the point! I found the answer to my question in the comments under the question. Now I will experiment. Every page of my site is correctly configured by "Last-Modified, If-Modified-Since and 304 Not Modified". People write that this may be one of the reasons.

Comment: Sorry for editing your question then.   I was trying to find something other than "please review my site" in your question.