# Why all URLs of my website has been excluded?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, sitemap

I've submitted my new site a week ago on google search console, but now I see that all of my URLs are excluded and the status is `Crawled - Currently not indexed`. Why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Relevant highlights from [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content): A week is not enough.  It usually takes Google a couple weeks to react to changes. Google rarely fully indexes new web sites right away. Google usually starts by indexing a few pages.  It usually takes Google months before it trusts a website enough to index a significant portion of it.

Answer (score 2):

The status **Crawled —currently not indexed** is indicating that the content is eligible to appear in Google's index, but Google is electing not to include it (that differs from being excluded).

You submitted a new site a week ago, you must be patient as Google needs to analyze your site before indexing it. Meanwhile, take a look at [Google Sandbox](https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-sandbox/) concept and review [some actions](https://www.contentkingapp.com/academy/index-coverage/faq/crawled-currently-not-indexed/) in order to speed up the process:

- **Poor internal link structure**: make sure your relevant pages have enough links. If you find important pages that you really want to rank with, add more internal links to them from pages higher in your website's architecture (especially from the homepage).
- **Poor content quality**: double-check whether your content is likely to satisfy user-intent, and adds more value than competing content on other sites.
- **Duplication**: check if your relevant pages are (near) duplicates of other pages, and should actually be canonicalized.
- **Domain Authority too low**: if the site is new maybe your domain authority is too low. You're publishing more content than Google is willing to index for your site. Gaining more backlinks will increase your domain authority.