# Enable Crawl for Google Search on Public Documents with Metadata in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, azure

I have an existing sharepoint site which contains both pages and documents under single domain name. Currently Google search console is setup to crawl this site and in sitemap.xml we are adding urls for both pages and documents.

Now going forward the documents will move out of the sharepoint site and will reside in Azure Blob storage. On sharepoint site url references will be updated and if anyone has bookmarked it it will be redirected to new document repository in Azure Storage. This azure blob repository currently has an domain url of its own but it will soon become the subdomain of original site. e.g. `https://documents.example.com`

Now we added this new document repository site (Azure Blob storage) also in Google search console and also added sitemap.xml containing all public documents. Post this setup we are facing fallowing issue with Google crawl -

1. For most of the items we are getting status as Crawled: Currently
   not indexed and they are not getting shown in search results. How
   can we fix this and recrawl this document?
2. For some of documents which do shows up it is showing random description and document name not the display title and description. How can we enable the valid display title and description for documents?

Document Types used are : pdf, docx

Comment: Listing URLs in a sitemap is not enough to get them indexed.   See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Comment: As for why Google might not be indexing all documents see [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)  Google almost never indexes all documents from a site, especially when the site is new, the documents are not prominently linked, or there is duplicate content involved.

Comment: What domain name are you using for the blob storage?  Is it on a subdomain of your main domain?

Comment: Where are these documents linked from your site.  What do those links look like?  Do they have anchor text of the title of the document?