# NextJS site hosted on Heroku not indexed by Bing after 2 months

Tags: bing, bing-webmaster-tools, next.js

[image]

my website does not get indexed for some reason.  I think its because of javascript.  I have been asking this question now for a long time, every one says there is no content or there is no back links.  But i don't think that is why my site is getting not indexed.

I think its because i have used NextJS and my server is Heroku.  How do i get indexed?

Comment: Did you read and follow the Bing Webmaster Guidelines as mentioned in the red box?  Have you contacted Heroku support?

Comment: yes they all are  correct

Answer (score 2):

Bingbot does not execute JavaScript, so any content on your pages that requires JavaScript to execute on the client isn't going to get indexed in Bing.  Bingbot effectively sees a nearly blank home page on your site with no links.

You need to implement Server Side Rendering (SSR).  [NextJS comes with with the ability to do so](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages):

> By default, Next.js pre-renders every page. This means that Next.js generates HTML for each page in advance, instead of having it all done by client-side JavaScript. Pre-rendering can result in better performance and SEO.

However the list of questions on your home page is **not** pre-rendered. It is only inserted into the page by JavaScript. To get Bing to index your site you will need to follow the NextJS instructions for getting this data into the pre-render. Because it appears to be dynamic data, you will probably want to use SSR for it as opposed to compile time pre-rendering.

Googlebot should be able to index a site that requires JavaScript, so your home page may eventually get indexed by Google, even without SSR. However the list of questions takes too long to load for me. Google gives up on rendering JavaScript after just a few seconds.

Even for Google, the list of questions on your home page isn't crawlable. Each question renders as `<div role="alert" class="fade question13 alert alert-primary show">World Test Championship</div>` with an `onclick` event that takes you to the page for the question. To be crawlable, that needs to render using an `<a href=...>` link so that Google can find the URL for each question. You already do this in the list of related questions on each question page, so you need to do the same thing for the home page.

There are also other problems with your site that may prevent many of your pages from getting indexed.  These are covered in more detail on [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content).

- Your site is "thin content." Very few of your the questions on it are answered. Most pages have only a couple lines of text from the question itself. Pages need hundreds of words on average to have enough content to get indexed.
- Your site in new. It can take search engines a year to index more than a few pages on a site.

After you solve your technical problems with indexing, you should work on improving the overall usefulness of your site and be patient. I wouldn't expect search engines to start indexing much of your site very soon.