# 3 months since my pages are blocked with status "Discovered - currently not indexed"

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I am trying to get my website fully indexed by google. Google has indexed 30 pages out of 92. So Google still have to index 62 pages. Since January I have 54 pages out of these 62 that are blocked with the status "Discovered - currently not indexed". I have tried to update their content with no luck, I also tried to get more backlinks also with no luck, then I also tried to submit the pages for index one by one, with no luck...

Here a page that is affected by this issue: https://estimationfrancaise.fr/affiliate

Anyone with a tip to understand how to dig and get more information on why Google doesn't index them?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is answered by [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content).  TL;DR Google rarely indexes 100% of any website. Pages won't be indexed if they are low reputation, low value, or duplicate. It often takes a year or more to build the reputation of your site to the point where Google will index 90% of it.

Comment: Does Google tell you if a page is flagged as "duplicate"?

Comment: If Google thinks a URL is duplicate it will usually report it in Search Console's "inspect URL" tool with a "Google-selected canonical" as an alternative.  That usually matches the user-declared canonical if one exists, but not always matches.

Comment: got it, thanks :)