# Site showing on Google Maps but not Google search

Tags: google-search

My website is showing on google maps, but not on Google search unless I specifically search for the website name.

If I enter "House for Sale Jersey" on Google maps, the website lists at around 7th. If I enter the same on Google search then it does not list at all.

If I enter either the full website name or the website URL into Google search it is listed. The website name is https://www.51clubley.com/

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content) and [What are the best ways to improve a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-improve-a-sites-position-in-google)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a search engine optimization issue. Google looks at many things in order to decide what page it is set on for search terms.

For instance: your site is not optimized for mobile phones, and also has a broken page layout. Google looks at those things when they rank a page.

You also need to pay attention to things like writing descriptive text which includes keywords that people will use to search for your site, using correct heading tags, using proper meta tags, setting up a sitemap for your site and [submitting it to google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/build-sitemap), optimize your images so they aren't big and slow down your site. These are just for starters.

For some brief advice, [take a look at this site](https://www.seomechanic.com/why-is-my-website-not-showing-in-google-search-results/).

Comment: Hi - thanks for the above answer. Using SerpApi, I can see that if I search for "House For Sale Jersey" my site does not make the search results. If I  restrict the search to local Google Local, then I rank number 4.