# Google chooses the home page rather than the language subdirectory to index and doesn't index any of the rest of the site

Tags: seo, canonical-url

My website URL is `text.example.com/en/`
and the same URL is also defined in the canonical tag, but Google selects a different canonical URL by itself in which it does not include the language path so the selected URL by Google is
`test.example.com`.

Because of this problem, any further URL on this domain is not indexed. Can we define the canonical URL in `sitemap.xml` to solve this? If so, how to add the canonical URL in the sitemap?

Comment: I highly doubt that this issue is causing Google to ignore the rest of your site.  It is far more likely that Google isn't indexing your site because  your site is less than a year old, isn't crawlable, or has quality problems.  See [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: What content is on `https:test.example.com/` (without the `en/`)?  Is Google indexing that?

Comment: yes google is indexing the url without /en/ and i can not edit the html to make the canonical tag correct because the page is setup on this subdomain with a CMS, where you can not edit the code, 

due to this issue google indexing the url without the /en/ and not indexing any article published because each article url carries the /en/

Comment: also a canonical tag is automatically added, with the /en/