# Page can be indexed but "URL is unknown to Google"

Tags: seo, google-search-console, technical-seo

Ahhhh... this is doing my head in!

I've got a bunch of URLs that are in my sitemap, able to be indexed, URLs have been live for a couple years etc. but they are "unknown to Google".

I'd love it if anyone has experienced this before and can provide some pointers?? :)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe a relevant portion of your sitemap might help others to answer it.

Comment: If you look at the pages and compare them how much information exists on these pages which is unique? If the answer to that question is very little, then they are either thin or duplicate content or both; And, Google isn't going to add them until they have unique content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: Please do not roll back mod edits, thanks. As stated in the edit description, 
"Please note that the community generally discourages links to sites since they're often associated with individual website reviews (which are considered off-topic), spam, and self-promotion." More context in [this meta thread](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/an-old-member-removed-the-link-to-my-site-on-the-question-should-i-re-add-it).

Comment: We really don't do individual site troubleshooting or reviews here (see: [Only could apply to your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), and generally mark questions about indexing that don't have enough details to be answered on their own as a duplicate of our community wiki linked to [above](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content).

Comment: The `URL is unknown to Google` status is for URLs that are _not_ indexed, but it appears you're saying they are indexed? If the URLs aren't actually indexed, then see [Page is not indexed: URL is unknown to Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en#index_coverage&zippy=%2Cpage-indexing-can-google-fetch-and-index-the-page). As suggested there, you should:  `run a live inspection and examine the page availability. Fix any issues that you can, then submit the page for indexing. and validate your fix.` The question marked as a duplicate may offer some other helpful ideas.