# Technical SEO: 8 month old site still is NOT indexed

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index, crawl-errors, technical-seo

Around 8 months ago, I launched a new website. I wrote about 200 articles for the website to get complete topical authority about the subject. Now 8 months later, I would expect to start seeing some traffic (been steadily linkbuilding aswell). However, over the last 3 months my traffic has stayed the same (around 500-600 ish). It even looks likes it is starting to dip a bit.

Anyway, I was looking through search console to try to identify what is 'wrong'. I currently have these problems (translations below):

[image]

From top to bottom, the translations are:

- Not found (404)
- Page with redirect
- Crawled - currently not indexed
- Found - currently not indexed
- Google chose different canonical page than user

### Error #1 - not found

When I started the site, I was still deciding on a proper structure. I was already uploading blogs at that point. In the end, I changed the url structure from:

`https://cvtips.nl/cv-opmaak/cv-indeling/` To `https://cvtips.nl/cv-opbouw/cv-indeling/`, because it made more sense. However, the 42 pages that have a 404 are all the ones that still have the first url structure. What is the best way to deal with this? I changed the url structure months ago... Adding 42 redirects also seems a bit wild. I changed all the internal links aswell, so there is not a single internal link that mentions an url with `/cv-opmaak/` in it.

### Error #2 - page with redirect

Not too worried about this to be honest. This has to do with a trailing slash at the end of the url. It is weird though, because I checked every single internal link on my site and found a few that did not have a trailing slash, so I changed those. The error does not dissapear though.

### Error #3 & #4: Crawled - not indexed/Found - not indexed

This is where it starts to become weird for me. I've read a few [blogs](https://www.onely.com/blog/how-to-fix-crawled-currently-not-indexed-in-google-search-console/) about this, and they say it could have something to do with low quality content or maybe the site not having enough crawl budget? All my blogs are written by me, have unique content and are at least 1000 words each. In total it says that 78 of my pages are not indexed... that is quite a lot after 8 months no?

I am really struggling with this site. I know it takes a long time to start ranking, but I suspect there's more to it with this site. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't have to have 42 individual redirect rules.  If you just moved a directory, a single redirect rule should handle all 42 URLs in that directory.

Comment: Your 3rd and 4th error are covered by [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content).  In short, it is not unusual at all for Google to choose not to index pages from a new site.  It takes a couple years to get 90% of your pages indexed. Almost every site has at least a few pages that Google chooses not to index.  How many of your pages ARE indexed?  What percent is that?  Has the number of indexed pages been growing over the last few months?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have around 200 blogs online. So 78 pages would be about 40% not indexed. `site:cvtips.nl` has around 80 pages indexed... Search console itself says it's about 50/50. The main takeaway from the post you linked it basically that I shouldn't worry about it for the time being?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller So you mean a single redirect from `/cv-opmaak/` to `/cv-opbouw/` correct?

Comment: I would try a different approach. Perform a site-wide technical audit of your site. There are several paid and free tools out there that can help you with that. You may uncover lots of issues that require fixing. Top of my mind free tools include Screaming Frog, or site audits from Ahrefs, Bing and Yandex.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran Yeah, I got ahrefs. Site audit shows a couple of issues, but nothing major. Just a few orpan pages that I fixed already. Also robots.txt seems to be inaccessible. Other than that it has a 95 score.

Comment: Here's a tool to verify that robots.txt is accessible for the different Google's bots: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool

Comment: For Error1, you have 2 options: redirect with 301 or drop with 404. If the content is the same, and only the location has changed, 301 is the best thing. There are several ways to accomplish that, like Stephen said before, if they were all on the same directory a single redirect is all you need.

Comment: For Error2, ensure that all pages EITHER end with a trailing slash or don't end with it. And create a rule to redirect in automatic from one to the other. This will prevent duplicate penalties in the future. I would also recommend setting up a canonical tag to prevent any confusion from the search engines.

Comment: For Error3, there isn't much to do but wait it out. I've heard people trying to force the issue by going into the URL Inspection tool for each URL, and there's a button to ask Google to index the page. I think it's overkill, and it doesn't guarantee anything. But you could try with a few pages to see if it works for you.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran Cool tool for checking robots.txt, thanks. I created a single 301 redirect for the directory. Canonical tag is already set up. Every single url ends with a slash, but the problem still persists in search console.

Comment: Have you tried making a giant sitemap with all your pages and submitting it to google? If the number of pages you have on Google search console doesn't add up to the overall number of pages of your site. Then often the problem can be failure to submit the pages originally. Like I added up your pages with errors and it ads up to 148. Check to see if your page count matches. Also, if you have a sitemap, you can probably solve your 404 errors by making sure the site map has the right link and the referring pages have the right links. You can go in and see 1 by one what referring pages exist.

Comment: @LeonardTreman Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I got a sitemap with all the correct links :)