# Webpage in Google Search Console moved from "Indexed" to "Crawled - currently not indexed"

Tags: google, google-search-console

One of my webpages that I added to my site a month ago became indexed after a few days. However in Google Search Console the page is now listed as "Crawled - currently not indexed." Confusingly, when I inspect that URL on google search console it says on the details page that the URL is indexed, so I'm not able to see a reason for why it's not indexed. (I've confirmed that the page is in fact not indexed since it doesn't appear when I do a site: search for it.)

Any ideas what would cause it to first become indexed and then later become not indexed?

Comment: A list of possible reasons is not really a good fit for this site due its format so we created a community wiki for that [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content). You can also review some of our other related questions [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=Crawled+-+currently+not+indexed).