# SEO issue - Page with redirect - on Hugo website

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, hugo

I have a static website (Hugo on Netlify).

On Google Web Console in Page indexing I have 190 pages not indexed, but only 78 indexed.

When I analyzed my website with Ahrefs, it showed that my pages have 301 redirect.

I don't have any redirect in netlify.toml or in static directory.

Here is my result from httpstatus.io [image]

I'll be much appreciated for any advice - where to start digging?

Comment: Can you share the link to the site and if there is an open source repository?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Having only a portion of your pages indexed is normal.  Google starts indexing a few pages from a site and as the sites reputation grows over years, it may eventually index 90% of it.  Very few websites get 100% of their pages indexed.  See [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: Can you share the URLs that it says are redirecting?