# Search engine indexing problem

Tags: seo, bing-webmaster-tools, bingbot

I have a WordPress website and I have problems getting it indexed by Bing. If I use the Bing Webmaster Tools, 'Inspect URL', the result is:

*The inspected URL is known to Bing but has some issues which are preventing indexation. We recommend you to follow Bing Webmaster Guidelines to increase your chances of indexation.*

The page gets indexed by Google.
I went through the guidelines, but I can't find anything that would prevent it from being indexed. I used Yoast as SEO tool.
Anyone with similar problems and maybe suggestions of the why and how?

Comment: See also: [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)