# Fix "Crawled - currently not indexed" in GSC

Tags: google-search-console

I have pages in google search console that has been showing "Crawled - currently not indexed".

Things I already tried:

- No error showed in GSC
- checked robots.txt
- [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content). This page doesn't contain this error and has no information about this specific issue
- waited 1 year
- GSC live test returned:

```
URL is available to Google
If it gets indexed and selected as canonical, it could appear in 
Google Search results with all relevant enhancements. Learn more
```

How can I diagnose the issue

Comment: The entire [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content) is about this problem.  Googlebot has come and crawled your pages, but decided it doesn't want to index them.

Comment: I've never seen a site that gets 100% of its pages indexed.  By the time your site is a year old, I would expect that you should be able to have tens of pages indexed (but probably not hundreds of pages.)  How many pages do you actually have and how many are currently indexed?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for comment. You are not wrong but It's just too general, I have 100 pages, 50 pages indexed. Site is up for 8 years. used to cover all pages but since I removed date from url a 1.5 yr ago this happened

Comment: 50% of your pages indexed isn't unusual. I don't think we can offer more specific advice than [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content).  Check that the content is original, high quality, long enough, and linked from other sites.

Comment: @user41209 There's really no way for us to be able to answer this specifically, and just listing all the possible reasons would fall under a community wiki, which is why we have [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content). That is why most of the questions we receive about Google errors and warnings are marked as a duplicate of this community wiki, which you can see from [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=Crawled+-+currently+not+indexed+is%3Aq) search.

Comment: @user41209 I'd suggest following Google's guide [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203?hl=en) to help figure out what the possible issues might be.

Comment: @dan, I don't get why you close the question. This behavior discourages people from answering the question. If you think the knowledge isn't available right now maybe that change depending on a future person who figures this out.
The answer mentioned there is not solving my issue. My contents are original cuz I wrote them and high quality as there is no post out there addressing them and this just happened after I changed my URL scheme. please reconsider
My website was 98% indexed but not anymore, because of change or something else

Comment: @user41209 As indicated above by two moderators, and evident by the search [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=Crawled+-+currently+not+indexed+is%3Aq), we mark questions asking about these types of errors and warnings as duplicates of our community wiki catch-all question. We're not able to answers these questions because we don't know any details about your specific site, what changes occurred, or reports...and questions seeking guesses or [lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic) of possible reasons are considered off-topic here.

Comment: @user41209 In addition to the community wiki, please take a look at the section in Google's guide that I linked to above: `Troubleshooting / Understand and fix common indexing issues`. Many of the issues listed there and in our community wiki can lead to these types of warnings, but you'll need to examine your site and reports in Google Search Console to see which ones might apply.

Comment: @dan Thanks. I see

Comment: @user41209 OK. Reviewing your comments from above: "...since I removed date from url a 1.5 yr ago this happened" -- if you meant that you changed your URLs in any way, they will no longer be indexed unless you create a `301` redirect to the new URL (i.e., the URLs with the dates removed). Even then it can take some time for Google to recrawl and index the new URLs. You can _possibly_ speed that up by submitting a sitemap. Going through Google's guide on troubleshooting and fixing indexing issues might point out other things you haven't thought of too. Good luck.

Comment: @dan Hey dan. I'm really tankful to your comment you were right and I did check that and now I understand,
I did create 301 redirect since 1.5yr ago and google saw that too, site map also updated. All were automatic. Anyway appreciate the time you put