# Indexing a google website

Tags: domains, google-search, search-engine-indexing, page

I have a very modest google website (something like https://sites.google.com/view/mymodestpage), created it by using the the google sites dashboard, nothing especial, just an informative page. However, I can't find my webpage when googling it, although when I try by duckduckgo and bravesearch it is indexed just fine.

How can I index my webpage in google? Whether do I have to buy a custom domain?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Have you setup your Search Console property and requested a crawl?

Comment: Related: [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: @A_Patterson, thanks for the comment. I've tried to setup the Search Console, but it asks for me to upload an HTML file to the google website, and I could not find any option at google site dashboard for uploading acustom HTML file, found only for embeding HTML snippets.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister thank you so much.